# Роутинг с помощью useRouter() в next.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, route, next.js, next

При переходе на страницу, `useRouter()` не отображает некоторые данные

Имеется компонент поиска, который при нажатии enter переносит нас на другую страницу:

```
<input className={styles.input}
        placeholder=""
        type="text"
        name="search"
        value={search}
        onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
        onKeyDown={handleKeyDown} />
```

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState<string>('');
const router = useRouter();

const goToSearch = () => {
    router.push({
        pathname: '/search',
        query: {
            search: search
        }
    });
};

const handleKeyDown = (e: any) => {
    if (e.key == 'Enter') {
        goToSearch();
    }
};
```

В папке `pages` есть файл `search.tsx`, который отрисовывает страницу после нашего перехода.

```
export const Search = () => {
    const router = useRouter()

    console.log(router)
    return (
        <>Seacrh</>
    );
}

export default Search;
```

Но при этом в консоль выводится

```
ServerRouter {
  route: '/search',
  pathname: '/search',
  query: {},
  asPath: '/search',
  isFallback: false,
  basePath: '',
  locale: undefined,
  locales: undefined,
  defaultLocale: undefined,
  isReady: false,
  domainLocales: undefined,
  isPreview: false,
  isLocaleDomain: false
}
```

Вопрос: как мне получить `query: {search: search}`?

Comment: Вам наверное нужен хук `useLocation`

Comment: А у тебя при переходе на /search добавляются query параметры?(Вот так /search?search=qwe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я воспроизвел Ваш код и у меня все работает. Есть еще один способ получить query из контекста:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next'

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  return {
    props: {
      query: context.query
    },
  }
}

export const Search = ({query} : {query: string}) => {
  const router = useRouter()

  console.log('router:' , router)
  console.log('query:', query)
  return (
    <h1>search</h1>
  );
}

export default Search;

/* router: {pathname: '/search', 
            route: '/search', 
            asPath: '/search?search=hello', 
            query: {search: 'hello'}…}
*/

// query: {search: 'hello'}

pages/
  _app.tsx
  index.tsx
  search.tsx
```

Comment: Из документации: query: Object - The query string parsed to an object, including dynamic route parameters. It will be an empty object during prerendering if the page doesn't use Server-side Rendering. Defaults to {}